# why does postMessage collapse arrays of [undefined]

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, web-worker

related to this question: [Javascript worker.postMessage shrinks empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770305/javascript-worker-postmessage-shrinks-empty-array/38770532#38770532)

When an array that contains `undefined` elements is given to `Worker.prototype.postMessage` the array that arrives has been messed with. It's length remains the same, but it is no longer possible to iterate using `.map`, `.reduce`, `for...in` etc.

The below code outputs `2 0`. Is this a bug, or is it somehow expected behavior? The same happens if you pass an array with partial values `[undefined, 2]` or `[1, undefined]` for example.

```
var response = "self.onmessage=function(msg){console.log(msg.data.length, msg.data.reduce(function(i){return ++i;},0))}";

var blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/javascript'});
var worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob))
worker.postMessage([undefined, undefined])
```

Comment: I suggest that you define worker function as a function and then convert it to string. That makes code much more readable, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33432215/607407

Comment: Also, how is this question different than the related one. Could you clarify? I can confirm this happens in google chrome and not firefox. If you cannot clarify what are you asking that wasn't already asked this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @TomášZato, the related question defines a `new Array(2)` which gets collapsed to an actual empty array `[]`. This was what happened when I tried removing the `new Array(2)` and replacing it with `[undefined, undefined]` it gets collapsed into an array with length = 2, but no indicies.